# Can this logic about locating a point uniquely without using "-" be challenged?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I was just exploring a possibility of locating point without using "-" ( negative ) sign. 
( Actually negative sign confuses me a lot when understanding the basics of coordinate geometry )

So, here is the line where actually

c1 = -1

c0 = 0

c2 = +1

-------------c1------------c0-------------c2--------------

To tell any person standing on "c0" to go to c1 , i can tell go to [-1,0] vector  or  1 unit left. Similarly to go to c2, i can say go to 1 unit right, or simply  [1,0] vector.

Instead of using negative sign, can the following information help a person standing on "c0", to identify c1 and c2 without confusion :

That is,

1) c0 is 1 unit away from c1

2) c0 is 1 unit away from c2

3) c1 is 2 unit away from c2

The good thing is, this does not involve any negative sign. Can this be challenged for ambiguity by the standing person ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're saying - you want to describe the location of points without giving explicit coordinates.

Note that your description (like any description involving only distances) cannot fix which way round all the points are. For example, switching $c_1$ with $c_2$ leaves all the distances unchanged, as does spinning everything around in the plane.

As for minus signs: this is exactly the same as a number line - are you comfortable with the idea of negative numbers stretching off to the left while positive ones go right?

Comment: yep! 
And the associated methamatics with it.
-1 x -1 = +1       or    
-1 - ( -1 ) = 0
That adds a lot of confusion, while working on something big.
Also, "minus" is something unreal, and cannot be compared with real world always. Also, if everything is mirrored, i don't think, it will cause any harm, since the whole world will be mirrored in that case.